# Run 'app' always disabled after cancel building process

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

[image]

I am using Android Studio **Artic Fox|2020.3.1 Patch 3**. Every time I click `Run 'app'` button then I cancel the building process, the `Run 'app'` button is always disabled and won't back to normal state. My current workaround is to press `Debug 'app'` until the app successfully run or to restart the Android Studio, so the `Run 'app'` button back to normal again.

Is this bug in Android Studio? how to fix it? I faced it since long time ago and never get solved until today

Comment: Are you using mac? With M1 chip?

Comment: @KaranMehta I am using ubuntu and windows, both of them have same problem

Comment: Looks like that is just a generic android studio issue as same thing happens on my mac as well.